# How do i get the height of the input?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to add a plugin to a input field. How to I get the height?

```
$("#age").myownplugin();

<input type="text" id="age" />
```

and inside myownplugin i've tried

```
alert( $(this).height )
```

without the result.

Comment: Could you show a bit more code from your plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

height is a method: `$(this).height();`

Comment: Inside the plugin just `this.height()` is enough

Comment: i get Uncaught ReferenceError: height is not defined @ jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16

Comment: you have to incluse jquery api for that-it's included in 1.4.1

Answer (score 12):

You can use these methods:

#### height + padding + border:

```
$(this).outerHeight()
```

.

#### height + padding + border + margin:

```
$(this).outerHeight(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

i don't know about your plugin structure, but height is a method so you have to use it like a method :).
for example-if you try this in your js, you will get the height of input box.

```
$('#age').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(elem).attr("height")` too.